# How to disable a row in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In have to disable a row in which chechbox is checked.I have tried it in RowDataBound event by using following code but it shows error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

```
  CheckBox cbAttachClrReq = (CheckBox)gvEntity.FindControl("chkAdd");

  if (cbAttachClrReq.Checked)
  {
      this.gvEntity.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex].Enabled = false;
  }
```

Comment: Assuming the `chkAdd` is inside a row, you will not find it when searchding in the `GridView`, you have to search inside the row itself because every row will contain it's own checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a chance that your `CheckBox` object is `null`. So i have also added a `null` check in the code.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    CheckBox cbAttachClrReq = e.Row.FindControl("chkAdd") as CheckBox;

    if (cbAttachClrReq != null && cbAttachClrReq.Checked)
        e.Row.Enabled = false;
}
```

**ADDED** based on valuable suggestion from comments, you can even toggle the `CheckBox` state if the object is `null`:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    CheckBox cbAttachClrReq = e.Row.FindControl("chkAdd") as CheckBox;
    e.Row.Enabled = cbAttachClrReq == null || !cbAttachClrReq.Checked;
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution, check if the current row is a `DataRow` (it can also be a header, footer, pager or spacer, see [DataControlRowType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolrowtype.aspx)), find the `CheckBox` on this row instance and see if exists (is not `null`) and if it's checked. You might want to change this answer way to `Enable` the row if the checkbox is not set to allow toggling.

Comment: You have given a good direction regarding toggle but according to the question statement "disable a row in which chechbox is checked", means CheckBox is in the same row.

Comment: I meant to suggest probably the goal is to Enable and Disable a row based on it's checkbox, so code would look something like `e.Row.Enabled = cbAttachClrReq == null || !cbAttachClrReq.Checked;`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following...i assume that checkbox is in gridview rows....

```
protected void gvEntity_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       CheckBox cbAttachClrReq = (CheckBox) e.Row.FindControl("chkAdd");

      if (cbAttachClrReq.Checked)
      {
          e.Row.Enabled = false;
      }       
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following...i assume that checkbox is in gridview rows's Cell....

```
protected void gvEntity_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       CheckBox cbAttachClrReq = (CheckBox) e.Row.Cells[yourCellIndexOFChBox].FindControl("chkAdd");

      if (cbAttachClrReq.Checked)
      {
          e.Row.Enabled = false;
      }       
    }

}
```